# Ubuntu allow max ram usage for sbt java

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, ram

sometimes during coding I realize that I have 100% ram used, and swap 100% ;)

Is it possible to dissalow for some processes like java, sbt etc. not to use more when for example 90% of ram is used already ?

Comment: what would you want to happen when they try to get more memory?

Comment: @MarcusMüller shutdown or at least show notification for me for example.

Comment: well, the OOM killer does exactly that for you: kill the most memory-hungry processes that misbehave during a high memory-pressure time. You can configure it!

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks! I will try to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your normal Out-of-memory killer perform that operation; first you'd put the "early to be killed" processes into an appropriate [cgroup (v2) with memory control](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#memory), and start throttling their memory demands as memory pressure rises; then your default-configured systemd-oomd will take care of killing the least well-behaving (by these metrics) processes.

Comment: hmm I have ubuntu 20.04: udo -s sysctl -w vm.oom-kill=1
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/vm/oom-kill: No such file or directory
❯ sudo -s sysctl vm.oom-kill
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/vm/oom-kill: No such file or directory

Comment: looks like there is earlyoom

Comment: not what I recommended; `systemd-oomd`!